# Random password functionality

Tags: php, passwords

I am having requirement to give my users a function to generate a safe password...

I have the algo in my mind but don't know how to process with it..

1. I will have a set of characters to provide in the password
2. I will have control over size of password that means select length
3. Select random indices from the array to get passsword of my selcected length...

Last part is what I can't implement..

Any help will be appreciated...

```
function randompassword() {  // Declaring the function
//Config Start
$salt = "abchefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789"; // Your characters bank
$n = "8";                                   // Number of character to return
//end config

//Logic for password generation..

return $pass;
}
```

Comment: Are you unable to find a function that returns random numbers in PHP?

Comment: So you want to add multiple generated passwords to an array and then choose one randomly?

Comment: Why is your "characters bank" called `$salt`? In programming the term "salt" has a [very different meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$v = strlen($salt); 
$pass='';
srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
  $i = 1;
  while ($i <= $n) {
        $num = rand() % $v;
        $tmp = substr($salt, $num, 1);
        $pass = $pass . $tmp;
        $i++;
  }
```

You can try this code..

Comment: Random number are seeded automatically since PHP 4.2.0, you don't need to call `srand`.

Comment: Also, where does `$v` come from?

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this that allows you to manage strength of your password and customize what characters you want to put in your password.

```
function randomPassword($length=9, $strength=0) {
$vowels = 'aeuy';
$consonants = 'bdghjmnpqrstvz';
if ($strength & 1) {
    $consonants .= 'BDGHJLMNPQRSTVWXZ';
}
if ($strength & 2) {
    $vowels .= "AEUY";
}
if ($strength & 4) {
    $consonants .= '23456789';
}
if ($strength & 8) {
    $consonants .= '@#$%';
}

$password = '';
$alt = time() % 2;
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    if ($alt == 1) {
        $password .= $consonants[(rand() % strlen($consonants))];
        $alt = 0;
    } else {
        $password .= $vowels[(rand() % strlen($vowels))];
        $alt = 1;
    }
}
return $password;
```

}

Comment: +1, for a complex yet neat logic.
As for the variable namings, a separate variable "`$specialChars`" could have been used.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $salt = "abchefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for ($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
        $pass=$pass.$salt[rand(0,strlen($salt))];
    echo $pass;
?>
```

You may also add a `substr(sha1($pass),0,$n);` at the end

Answer (score 1):

It's really not that complicated:

```
$characters = 'abcd...';
$password   = '';
$length     = 8;

while (strlen($password) < $length) {
    $password .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
}
```

Comment: Why query the length of the string on each iteration when you are adding exactly one character each time, hence you KNOW the length?

Comment: I knew somebody would point out that this is not very optimal... Yes, you could optimize the hell out of this. I want to show a *simple* algorithm, since that's apparently the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function unique_id2()
              {

             return substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 25);

            }
```

Comment: *"How many variables does it take to change a lightbulb?"* ;o)

Comment: I can't understand what you want to say? Please explain me in detail.

Comment: I'm saying that you have at least two, but pretty much *three superfluous variables* in that snippet. `$uniqueid = $unique_code;` is most certainly entirely unnecessary, but overall the whole thing could be written as `return substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 25);`, without *any* temporary variables.

Comment: yeah you are right. thanks for your suggestion. I am going to edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$password = "";
for($k=0;$k<$n;$k++){
 $rand = rand(0,strlen($salt));
 $password .=   $salt[$rand];
 }
echo $pass;
?>
```